# Visualize a bipartite graph in pyviz

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx, pyviz

I used networkx to visualize a bipartite graph but the result was unsatisfactory (i.e. nodes, text and edge labels overlapping). Now I am trying to use the pyviz library (https://pyviz.org/). The visual problems are now resolved but I can't find a way to separate the right and left side nodes in the outcome graph. Any suggestions on how can I make a nice looking bipartite graph in pyviz, or any other library?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Was there some reason the dedicated bipartite layout did not work for you in networkX?

See the example [from the documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout.html) below:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.bipartite.gnmk_random_graph(3, 5, 10, seed=123)
top = nx.bipartite.sets(G)[0]
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(G, top)

nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
```

Resulting in the below layout:

[image: bipartite layout]

Hope this helps.